# Cannot install gem debug

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, rubygems, vscode-extensions, wsl-2

I am trying to find a way to debug ruby program, I have the VSCode extension rbdg and when I tried to run the command in window terminal, it kept giving me error

`sudo gem install debug`

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debug:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/debug-1.9.1/ext/debug
/usr/bin/ruby3.0 -I /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby -r ./siteconf20240116-44057-ujy9lx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/debug-1.9.1/ext/debug
make DESTDIR\= clean
current directory: /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/debug-1.9.1/ext/debug
make DESTDIR\=
make failedNo such file or directory - make

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/debug-1.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/debug-1.9.1/gem_make.out
```

Specs

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
    Architecture: x86-64
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
gem -v
3.3.5
```

I couldn't find out how to edit my Gemfile for bundle install, it's my first time working with Ruby and Window wsl so I really don't know what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix =.='

**1. Install make command**

```
sudo apt install make
```

**2. Install build-essential**

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

After that, I could install debug gem package successfully.